# How to create refineslide image slide with independent preview images below using jquery and css?

Tags: jquery, css, image, slider

I am trying out the refineslide slider and it actually seems pretty cool so far. I've noticed from some other posts that there are some fellow users on in this forum so I thought I'd reach out.  Does anyone know how I would go about changing the smaller, "slider" images below so they arent using the same image as the rotating "hero" images above? I would like to use independent images for the bottom slider and the larger rotating images above.

There is a lot of code for this, which I do have up on a personal site so I created a fiddle which you can view below. (Apologies, this was my first fiddle so if something doesn't seem correct, please let me know and I will fix.)

http://jsfiddle.net/Buford/aMj6u/

(The code pasted below is only the html, the css and js can be seen at the link above.)

```
    <div class="wrap group">
        <div class="section-2 group">
            <ul id="images" class="rs-slider">
                <li class="group">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://thegravityghost.com/test/assets/img/wood6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="rs-caption rs-bottom">
                        <h3>Caption Area</h3>
                        <p>Wood texture by <a href="http://downloads.dvq.co.nz/" class="button">Matthew Skiles.</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="group">
                    <a href="#" class="slide-parent"><img src="http://thegravityghost.com/test/assets/img/greenbut.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                    <div class="rs-caption rs-top-right">
                        <p>This image is wrapped in a link.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="group">
                    <img src="http://thegravityghost.com/test/assets/img/form.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <div class="rs-caption rs-bottom-right">
                        <p>Adapted from <a class="button" href="http://dribbble.com/shots/154205-Cool-Green-Signup-form">Glenn Van Bogaert</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="group"><img src="http://thegravityghost.com/test/assets/img/red.jpg" alt=""/>
                </li>
                <li class="group"><img src="http://thegravityghost.com/test/assets/img/6.jpg" alt=""/></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- /.section-2 -->         
    </div> <!-- /.wrap -->



<script src="http://thegravityghost.com/test/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://thegravityghost.com/test/assets/js/jquery.refineslide2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $upper = $('#upper');

        $('#images')

        .refineSlide({
            transition : 'fade',
            onInit : function () {
                var slider = this.slider,
                   $triggers = $('.translist').find('> li > a');

                $triggers.parent().find('a[href="#_'+ this.slider.settings['transition'] +'"]').addClass('active');

                $triggers.on('click', function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault();

                    if (!$(this).find('.unsupported').length) {
                        $triggers.removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                        slider.settings['transition'] = $(this).attr('href').replace('#_', '');
                    }
                });

                function support(result, bobble) {
                    var phrase = '';

                    if (!result) {
                        phrase = ' not';
                        $upper.find('div.bobble-'+ bobble).addClass('unsupported');
                        $upper.find('div.bobble-js.bobble-css.unsupported').removeClass('bobble-css unsupported').text('JS');
                    }
                }

                support(this.slider.cssTransforms3d, '3d');
                support(this.slider.cssTransitions, 'css');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am still learning js and jquery, but I think the part of the js code that is driving the current "smaller" images in the slider is this:

```
    ,setThumbs: function () {
        var that = this,
            // Set percentage width (minus user-defined margin) to span width of slider
            width = (100 - ((this.totalSlides - 1) * this.settings.thumbMargin)) / this.totalSlides + '%';

        //<Wrapper to contain thumbnails
        this.$thumbWrap = $('<div class="rs-thumb-wrap" />').appendTo(this.$sliderWrap);

        // Loop to apply thumbnail widths/margins to <a> wraps, appending an image clone to each
        for (var i = 0; i < this.totalSlides; i++) {
            var $thumb = $('<a />')
                .css({
                    width : width,
                    marginLeft : this.settings.thumbMargin + '%'
                })
                .attr('href', '#')
                .data('rs-num', i);

            this.$slideImages.eq(i).clone()
                .removeAttr('style')
                .appendTo(this.$thumbWrap)
                .wrap($thumb);
        }

        this.$thumbWrapLinks = this.$thumbWrap.find('a');

        // Safety margin to stop IE7 wrapping the thumbnails (no visual effect in other browsers)
        this.$thumbWrap.children().last().css('margin-right', -10);

        // Add active class to starting slide's respective thumb
        this.$thumbWrapLinks.eq(this.settings.startSlide).addClass('active');

        // Listen for click events on thumnails
        this.$thumbWrap.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            that.transition(parseInt($(this).data('rs-num'))); // Call transition using identifier from thumb class
        });
    }
```

I do not know the correct way to update the syntax in order to achieve my original request (having the end result use different slider images than the rotating hero images above). Any help would be greatly appreciated.